# "TypeError: graphql.isType is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, testing, apollo, apollo-client

I’m running a GraphQL/Apollo/React stack and am trying to implement MockedProvider in my tests since it seems like a great way of abstracting away a lot of mocks. However, I keep running into the following error. I’ve tried updating, stepping through, and I’m still not sure why the import is failing. Any help would be great, thanks!

[My test code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muvYL.png)

**Test Code:**

```js
test.only('Renders with MockedProvider', () => {
  render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
      <DailyInspection />
    </MockedProvider>
  )
})
```

**Error:**

```js
TypeError: graphql.isType is not a function

       6 | import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
       7 | import DailyInspection from '../index'
    >  8 | import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing'
         | ^
       9 |
      10 | import {
      11 |   GetProjectControlPointsIdsAndGuidsDocument,

      at removeTemporaryGlobals (../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/globals/graphql.js:4:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/globals/index.js:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@apollo/client/testing/testing.cjs.js:6:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/views/DailyInspection/__tests__/DailyInspection.test.tsx:8:1)
```

Comment: Could be related to this?:
[graphql webpack 5 issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2721#issuecomment-723008284)

Comment: You need to create a minimal, reproducible example